# Displaying & highlighting glossary entries that are not defined yet?

Tags: hyperref, color, glossaries

In my document I use the `glossaries`package.

When referencing terms, that do not exist in the glossary (yet) 
the term is simply not displayed. Which IMHO forces a quite complex workflow.

Is there any possibility of **displaying** non-defined terms, but in a different color?

for example:

`\gls{DefinedTerm}` would be displayed in my default link-color and

`\gls{UndedinfedTerm}` would be displayed in another style, like red, underlined.

----**UPDATE**-----

The following does exactly what i was looking for:

```
\newcommand{\mygls}[1]{\ifglsentryexists{#1}{\gls{#1}}{\textcolor{red}{\underline{#1}}}}
```

put this in your preamble and simply use `\mygls{Term}`. Undefined terms will then be highlighted, while defined terms will be displayed using `\gls{}`

(see [JMs answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64164/16681))

Comment: Please see the update in my answer.  With the `\let` command, you can use only `\gls` and not worry about switching between your own command and using it.  As you update your glossary, the entries will naturally switch from being red/underlined to being used as a normal `\gls` entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**--UPDATE--**

I have updated the command as follows (you must include the `xcolor` pacakage in order to use the `\textcolor` command:

```
\let\originalgls\gls
\renewcommand{\gls}[1]{\ifglsentryexists{#1}{\originalgls{#1}}{\textcolor{red}{\underline{#1}}}}
```

You can now use the `\gls` command for all your entries, and as you define them, they will switch from being red/underlined to being used as a normal `\gls` entry.

**--END UPDATE--**

When I compile my thesis (which I'm in the middle of right now) and I include a `\gls{UndefinedTerm}` my compilation errors out, stating: "Glossary entry `UndefinedTerm` has not been defined".  Does your compilation not fail?  I would encourage you to simply add the terms as you go, it is truly not that cumbersome or time-consuming.

It even appears, looking at glossaries.sty, that it should throw an error (from lines 935-940 of glossaries.sty)
To someone more able, this may be the place to modify the code and create the output you need.

```
\newcommand{\glsdoifexists}[2]{%
  \ifglsentryexists{#1}{#2}{%
    \PackageError{glossaries}{Glossary entry `#1' has not been
    defined}{You need to define a glossary entry before you
    can use it.}}%
}
```

Otherwise, if all that the \gls for an undefined term will do is print it in red and underline, why not simply make a command for that.  You will have to go through the thesis and look for them anyway, then add the entry.  I still think that this will be more hassle at the end.

ugls for "Undefined gls"
`\newcommand{\ugls}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\underline{#1}}}`

Comment: Thank you so much for that! `\newcommand{\mygls}[1]{\ifglsentryexists{#1}{\gls{#1}}{\textcolor{red}{\underline{#1}}}}` did the trick!

Comment: Oh wonderful!  I hadn't thought of using the `\ifglsentryexists` command.  I may include that in my thesis as well.  Make sure to include the `xcolor` package for the `\textcolor` command.